# git clone is blank from a Gitosis Served Repository

Tags: git

Everything is working fine with my public keys and repository activity but when one of my team members tries to clone a repository, the clone is blank, example output:

```
bry4n@~/tests$ git clone git@server.com:tg/base.git
bry4n@~/tests$
```

At first, It was giving the typical no read access error. Then i stripped out alot of the junk out of the configuration then he started only getting the output above.

Comment: You might want to check out gitolite: http://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/wiki - one of the main advantages I found it to have, was a cleaner and more transparent design compared to gitosis. It also provides a migration process from gitosis.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to increase the gitosis log level. In your gitosis.conf use:

```
[gitosis]
loglevel = DEBUG
```

Now you should get a lot more information about what's going on.

Comment: thats one of the first things i did to the configuration when he told me he could not clone.

Comment: and you got no logs?